# Что в Python мешает установить модуль PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl

В среде интерпретатора Conda пытаюсь установить модуль PyOpenGL, но получаю ошибку:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyOpenGL (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyOpenGL

При этом ошибку сопровождает предупреждение:

> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rpcio (c:\users\zlatt\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)

Нашел в папке `site-packages` два каталога: `~rpc` и `~rpcio-1.36.1.dist-info`.

Еще был вариант зайти в папку `scripts` и уже оттуда запускать команду `pip install PyOpenGL`. Но также поймал предупреждение о `~rpcio-`

При попытке обновить сам установщик `pip` получил то же предупреждение насчет `~rpcio-`. Обновить не смог.

**P.S.** Удалил папки `~rpcio-` и `~rpcio-1.36.1.dist-info`. Но осталось другое предупреждениие:

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/pyopengl/

Ошибка сохранилась, модуль не загружен.

Моя версия Python 3.7.6, pip имеет версию 22.0.4

Как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решений оказалось два:

1. как написал ранее, из директории `\anaconda3\lib\site-packages` удалил два обозначенных выше каталога с символом тильды `~` перед их именем. По всей видимости, они создаются при обновлении версий соответствующих модулей.
2. ранее у меня не был подключен прокси и с проблемой не сталкивался. Теперь для загрузки библиотеки пришлось временно отключить прокси. Сделал это так:

- сочетание клавиш Windows+I;
- Выбрал `Сети и интернет`;
- Зашел в раздел `Прокси-сервер`;
- В строке `Настройка прокси вручную` выбрал `Выкл`.